# Can't manage to center thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, thumbnails, center

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework for my app, and thumbnails to show information about different products (6 divided into two rows). However, the thumbnails is left aligned and I can't manage to get them centered. How could that be done?

**html:**

```
<div class="row span12">
    <ul class="thumbnails span12">
        <li class="span3 product">
          <div class="thumbnail padding pagination-centered">
            Product 1
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 product">
          <div class="thumbnail padding pagination-centered">
            Product 2
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 product">
          <div class="thumbnail padding pagination-centered">
            Product 3
          </div>
        </li>
          <li class="span3 product">
          <div class="thumbnail padding pagination-centered">
            Product 4
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 product">
          <div class="thumbnail padding pagination-centered">
            Product 5
          </div>
        </li>
          <li class="span3 product">
          <div class="thumbnail padding pagination-centered">
            Product 6
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Output:**

```
     _____________________
    |                     |
    |  Products           |
    | ___   ___   ___     |
    ||   | |   | |   |    |
    ||___| |___| |___|    |
    | ___   ___   ___     |
    ||   | |   | |   |    |
    ||___| |___| |___|    |
    |                     |
    |_____________________|
```

**Desired output:**

```
     _____________________
    |                     |
    |  Products           |
    |   ___   ___   ___   |
    |  |   | |   | |   |  |
    |  |___| |___| |___|  |
    |   ___   ___   ___   |
    |  |   | |   | |   |  |
    |  |___| |___| |___|  |
    |                     |
    |_____________________|
```

Comment: What CSS are your trying on top of Bootstrap?

Comment: create a js fiddle and you'll probably get an answer much quicker

Comment: @MikeTedeschi: I've tried "margin: 0px auto" on the wrapping div... no luck.

Comment: @WebweaverD: Yeah I know, but it's actually not that easy because of the use of Twitter Bootstrap, which has a CSS file with ~6000 lines. Yes, all codes isn't necessary for this specific thing but a lot of things are, spread among that file.

Comment: @holyredbeard if you load jquery on the left there is an option to load the js for twitter bootstarp you can then add the css under add resources, just use a cdn link like this: <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set the uls width equal to the 3 elements added width + borders, margins and paddings. centering you can achive by setting left and right margins to auto.

see the demo
http://jsbin.com/odojit/2/edit

```
.thumbnails li {
  width:100px;
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
    border:solid black 1px;

}
ul {
  padding:0px;margin:0px;}
.span12 {
  width:368px;
  border:red solid 1px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

To override something like bootstrap, you need to have higher css specifity in your new code, which means higher priority.

As a rule of thumb:

Id selector is worth 10x as much as class selector which is 10 times as much as element selector.

```
#id div {code}
```

overrides

```
.class .class .class .class .class .class .class .class .class .class {css code}
```

Check this article for more details:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

So if bootstrap uses an ID selector, to overwrite it, you can use body #idselector, which will give it +1 specifity. !important also works, but doesnt allways work in IE6.

Comment: Thanks! Your code didn't work if used exactly as you wrote it, because of a lot of Twitter Bootstrap css. However, I changed "margin : 0px" in ul to "margin: auto !important", and that worked.

Comment: great, if there is a lot of css to override, you need high specifity, check this link on css specifity. also putting the new css after bootstrap should help. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this .........

```
.thumbnails li {
  width:100px;
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
    border:solid black 1px;

}
ul {
  padding:{0px;
```

margin:0px;
}

```
 <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li>
          <div class="thumbnail">
            Product 1
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="thumbnail">
            Product 2
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="thumbnail">
            Product 3
          </div>
        </li>
          <li>
          <div class="thumbnail">
            Product 4
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 producer">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            Product 5
          </div>
        </li>
          <li>
          <div class="thumbnail">
            Product 6
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```